# CSS & JavaScript - Anyway to emulate this JS behaviour with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some div such as :

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.background='#CCCCCC'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'">
```

So when i go on and out with the mouse, they change colour. Any way to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
div{
   background-color:#CCC;
}
div:hover{
   background-color:#FFF;
}
```

However, beware that this might fail in some browsers (IE6-) because `:hover` was at the start only meant to work with links.

Comment: Note, not all browsers support `:hover` on other elements than `a`.

Comment: Although it won't (and shouldn't) matter to most people, if you would like this code to work in IE6, you can use [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Comment: It *will* work on all browsers, check out the link that thirtydot posted.

Comment: on IE6 for example :) I wanted to know if there are any ways, but add patch/script to do workaround :) But ok, I'll surrender on this i think... :)

Comment: In fact, if the users use IE6 can't see this effect, but the div keep his aspect, right? So I can do it anyway....

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `<div>` as a link? Keep in mind that you can just use an actual anchor, `<a>`, and make it block level so it can maintain the width of height of your choosing.

```
a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to be a link-div, just get the effect :)